# Error when calculating the distance between two GPS coordinates

Tags: sql

Query I am using and I have tried many ways, and yet I can't figure out. Please help.

All the columns are in varchar(max) datatype

```
SELECT  
[Distance in Meters]  =  GEOGRAPHY::Point(ProvidedLat, ProvidedLon, 4326).STDistance(GEOGRAPHY::Point(FromFieldLat, FromFieldLon, 4326))
FROM TABLE
```

also tried like

```
SELECT  
[Distance in Meters]  =  GEOGRAPHY::Point(ProvidedLon,ProvidedLat, 4326).STDistance(GEOGRAPHY::Point(FromFieldLon,FromFieldLat, 4326))
FROM TABLE
```

sample data screenshot

[image: Sample data]

error message

> Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Line 109
> A .NET Framework error occurred during the execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "geography":
> System.FormatException: 24202: Longitude values must be between -15069 and 15069 degrees.
> System.FormatException:
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.Point(Double latitude, Double longitude, Int32 srid)

Comment: Is that all of the data? Do you definitely not have any data with an out-of-range Lat or Lon values, even one row? You could try adding WHERE BETWEENs all coordinates just in case.

Comment: @KenWhite. I am sorry, it's just I didn't realize they are all in caps and also I didn't know if something is in caps it means shouting and to be clear I am not shouting. Thank you.

Comment: @Rup. Thank you, I will check one more time.